Congratulations to fgrieu for earning over 100,000 reputation points!
crypto.se has recently acquired our second 100k rep user! The first one was poncho.
The user fgrieu has recently passed the 100k reputation marker. This is the second time this has ever happened on our site/.
This is a herculean achievement. For most users, acquiring 100,000 rep on crypto.se appears simply impossible - our site does not receive as much traffic and votes as some others do.
It required 1,498 answers and 131 questions over the course of 8 years, 8 months to get here. Additionally, many of those answers are of exceptional quality, extremely long, and educative.
According to how SE tracks such things, fgrieu has reached 2.9 Million people with their content on SE.
Let's hear it for fgrieu!

That's a well deserved achievement!
fgrieu has always well documented, deep answers, which I always enjoy reading.
We were recently joking about it on the Side Channel, but these are truly thesis-like answers sometimes.
And some of his questions are like puzzles, which I'd love to see solved.
Congrats, and keep them coming!

Contrats to fgrieu!
Not only is fgrieu the second user on Crypto earning 100k reputation but also the only user (so far) to gain the Socratic badge!
I will always enjoy reading the detailed answers and interesting questions from fgrieu.
Keep up the good work :D
